Need help finding similar phrases and analogies to "As Above, So Below," "Microcosm-Macrocosm Analogy," etc
I'm writing a little passion project hobby paper discussing and defining different metaphysics, alongside different latin phrases, and creating a grouping of which ones I find to be most applicable in defining the inner workings of the world.
The current title being Philosophical Fundaments of the Ubiquitous Being; A discussion of Metaphysics.
So far the main sections I have are;
Of elementary Philosophical definition (Quiddity; Haecceity; Qualia; Chaos; Order);
Of collective philosophical analysis of composite based theological symbolism (Saccidānanda; Taijitu/YinYang; holy trinity);
Of perspective concept (De dicto and De re; A priori and A posteriori; Agathusia and Aschimothusia);
Of Phenomenon, Noumenon, interaction of such, And lack thereof;
The different phrases of which to be inserted before each aforementioned sectioned concept (Ignoramus et ignorabimus; Quod me nutrit me destruit; Semper in excretia sumus, solim profundum variat; Sub specie aeternitatis).
Right now I'm having trouble filling up the last concept section, Of regard to philosophical scaling, similarities, and repetition. I only have two examples of such, that being 'As above so below,' and, 'Microcosm-Macrocosm Analogy.' I'm currently searching for more complete examples of such, as I feel that the two I currently have are far too vague, and would greatly appreciate if someone would help.

Perhaps your final chapter’s arrow from the said scaling, similarity and difference during Deleuzian style repetition points to ‘paradoxical’ self-reference with non-vague examples such as the perennial liar sentence and Russell’s set?…
